# Align pictures to depict

Tags: photography

I have photo taken in burst mode. I want to automatically realign them so I can superpose them to compare the change between them. Any non-Apple platform will do

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/87546/34947) you can use [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/) software. Here is the [manual](https://sites.google.com/site/qingzongtseng/template-matching-ij-plugin/tuto2) how to do it.

> 1. Open the stack called "stack to align.tif" ([download it here](https://sites.google.com/site/fileqzt/file/Template_Matching_sample.zip?attredirects=0)). You can see that it composed of several images of similar patterns but not
>    well aligned.
> 2. Run Plugins>Template Matching>Align slices in stack...
> 3. Click OK, then a dialog will appear to ask you to select a square ROI region as the landmark for aligning
> 4. After making a square ROI on the image stack, click on OK.
> 5. All the slices in the stack will be aligned, and the displacements for each slice are printed out in both log window and results table.